# Change background color of DialogButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-alertdialog

I am using [rflutter_alert](https://pub.dev/packages/rflutter_alert) and I currently want to Change background color of DialogButton in my Flutter app and I am not getting it. Where should I modify my code with the color chosen for the button?

```
 // Showing Alert Dialog with Response JSON Message.
    Alert(
      context: context,
      type: AlertType.error,
      title: "",
      desc: "Usuario/Correo o contraseña incorrecta",
      buttons: [
        DialogButton(
          child: Text(
            "Cerrar",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
          ),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          width: 120,
        )
      ],
    ).show();
  }
} on TimeoutException catch (e) {
  setState(() {
    visible = false;
  });
```

Comment: Are you using webDriver for Alert? or what is `Alert` in your case

Comment: i am not using webDriver

Comment: Can you include more about `Alert`

Comment: rflutter_alert:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: rflutter_alert
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Alert` provides `style` parameter that can be used to customize the default behavior.

```dart
Alert(
    style: AlertStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.amber),
```

More about [rflutter_alert](https://pub.dev/packages/rflutter_alert)